# gethostbyname use problem in webench source code

Tags: linux, networking

[source code here](https://github.com/52coder/webbench/blob/b04f95f3a63ea8cfc1c2223b81bfb58c98fdb0a1/socket.c#L47)

```
inaddr = inet_addr(host);
if (inaddr != INADDR_NONE)
    memcpy(&ad.sin_addr, &inaddr, sizeof(inaddr));
else
{
    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (hp == NULL)
        return -1;
    //does not have h_addr member
    memcpy(&ad.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
}
```

I am new to network programming,one of my friend told me to read the code of webench to learn basic use.I see the book unp,find struct hostent does not have the member of h_addr,in the book the example shows that h_aliases and h_addrtype is pointer to pointer,which means we can use in this way:

```
#include    "unp.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char            *ptr, **pptr;
    char            str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct hostent  *hptr;

    while (--argc > 0) {
        ptr = *++argv;
        if ( (hptr = gethostbyname(ptr)) == NULL) {
            err_msg("gethostbyname error for host: %s: %s",
                    ptr, hstrerror(h_errno));
            continue;
        }
        printf("official hostname: %s\n", hptr->h_name);

        for (pptr = hptr->h_aliases; *pptr != NULL; pptr++)
            printf("\talias: %s\n", *pptr);

        switch (hptr->h_addrtype) {
        case AF_INET:
            pptr = hptr->h_addr_list;
            for ( ; *pptr != NULL; pptr++)
                printf("\taddress: %s\n",
                    Inet_ntop(hptr->h_addrtype, *pptr, str, sizeof(str)));
            break;

        default:
            err_ret("unknown address type");
            break;
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I modify this to corret code,since h_addr_list may have more than one ipaddr,which value should I copy to ad.sin_addr.

Comment: `ptr = *++argv;` - While valid C, this is really horrible syntax.  It would get you a *redo* in most code reviews.  Surely there's a better example.

Comment: @Kingsley agree with you,this code come from unp v3  names/hostent.c